# Should i use new services for each table in my db.json?

Tags: angular

I am not sure whether i should use separe services(to get or/and delete data) for each table in my database. Or it is fine to keep them in one service? I think it would work either way, I am kinda new to Angular, so just asking for a proper answer.

```
db.json:

{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Product1",
      "description": "fdfdf",
      "price": 10.20
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Product2",
      "description": "fdfdf",
      "price": 20.00
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Product3",
      "description": "fdfdf",
      "price": 30.00
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Product4",
      "description": "fdfdf",
      "price": 40.00
    }
  ],
  "brands": [
    {
      "name": "brand1",
      "country": "country1"
    },
    {
      "name": "brand2",
      "country": "country2"
    },
    {
      "name": "brand3",
      "country": "country3"
    }
  ]
}

my service: 

export class ProductService {
  private url: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:3000';
  }

  public getJsonProducts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/products');
  }
  public getJsonBrands(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/brands');
  }
}
```

Comment: best practice is one service per resource.  Services should be small and focused.  Often a sort of base service will underlie many services, such as an http helper of some kind.  Keeping all resources in one service might be fine in a very simple app but anything remotely complex will become confusing and unmanageable. However, this is an opinion question and not a specfic programming problem, not suitable for SO

Comment: Does your database have only two tables? if so, it doesn't matter much. Does it have 100? If so, would you be comfortable with a class that will have hundreds of different methods, and that every developer will have to modify every time something needs to be changed or added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it kinda depends on the service you are calling. If the general structure of each table is the same, and you can control which endpoint to call and which parameters to pass from the method in the service, such as

```
// inside my service
getTableData(endpoint: string, params: paramInterface) {
    return this.http.post(`api/getTableData/${endpoint}`, { params }, { headers });
}
```

then it's completely fine and encouraged! since you are avoiding repetition of code (DRY principle).

On the other hand, if each table has different requests, then you should make each component have its service.

My approach though, would be to create an Abstract Table Service, that gets params on construction and then does the call using those params, and create a service in each component extending from that base abstract table service, that way you don't repeat code (DRY) but also can implement anything extra to any service, and each service does its own thing (separation of responsibilities).

Hope I enlighten with my answer instead of confusing more!